# ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209) Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose()

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I am facing [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose(): _AddToCardWidgetState#c0593(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)
And the error is printed as :

```
This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback.
E/flutter (26736): The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.
E/flutter (26736): This error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called because another object is retaining a reference to this State object after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory leaks, consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().
E/flutter (26736): #0      State.setState.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1085:9)
E/flutter (26736): #1      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1120:6)
E/flutter (26736): #2      _AddToCardWidgetState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:multi_vending_grocery_app/widgets/products/add_to_cart_widget.dart:57:11)
E/flutter (26736): #3      List.forEach (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:433:8)
E/flutter (26736): #4      _AddToCardWidgetState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:multi_vending_grocery_app/widgets/products/add_to_cart_widget.dart:55:26)
E/flutter (26736): #5      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1434:47)
E/flutter (26736): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Request fellow flutter, and dart developers to help me fix the issue. When I change the product quantity value from AddToCardWidget and navigate back to ProductListWidget the quantity value does not get updated there instead the error explained above displays in my android studio console. Help me fix it, I am new to flutter so can't solve it alone.

CODE FOR AddToCardWidget

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_easyloading/flutter_easyloading.dart';
import 'package:multi_vending_grocery_app/services/cart_services.dart';
import 'package:multi_vending_grocery_app/widgets/cart/counter_widget.dart';

class AddToCardWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddToCardWidget({Key? key, this.documentSnapshot}) : super(key: key);
  final DocumentSnapshot? documentSnapshot;

  @override
  State<AddToCardWidget> createState() => _AddToCardWidgetState();
}

class _AddToCardWidgetState extends State<AddToCardWidget> {
  final CartServices _cartServices = CartServices();
  User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  bool isLoading = true;
  bool exists = false;
  int _qty = 1;
  String? _docId;

  @override
  void initState() {
    getCartData();
    super.initState();
  }

  getCartData() async {
    final snapshot =
        await _cartServices.cart.doc(user?.uid).collection('products').get();
    if (snapshot.docs.isEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //If Product exist in car , we need to get qty details
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('cart')
        .doc(user?.uid)
        .collection('products')
        .where('productId', isEqualTo: widget.documentSnapshot?['productId'])
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
        if (doc['productId'] == widget.documentSnapshot?['productId']) {
          setState(() {
            exists = true;
            _qty = doc['qty'];
            _docId = doc.id;
          });
        }
      });
    });

    return isLoading
        ? Container(
            height: 56,
            child: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                    Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
              ),
            ),
          )
        : exists
            ? CounterWidget(
                documentSnapshot: widget.documentSnapshot,
                qty: _qty,
                docId: _docId.toString(),
              )
            : InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  EasyLoading.show(status: "Adding Product To Cart");
                  _cartServices
                      .addToCart(widget.documentSnapshot)
                      .then((value) {
                    setState(() {
                      exists = true;
                    });
                    EasyLoading.showSuccess("Added to Cart");
                  });
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 56,
                  color: Colors.red[400],
                  child: Center(
                    child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: const [
                            Icon(
                              CupertinoIcons.shopping_cart,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 10,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "Add to Basket",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
              );
  }
}
```

CODE FOR ProductListWidget

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:multi_vending_grocery_app/providers/store_provider.dart';
import 'package:multi_vending_grocery_app/services/product_services.dart';
import 'package:multi_vending_grocery_app/widgets/products/product_card_widget.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class ProductListWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProductListWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ProductServices _services = ProductServices();
    var _storeProvider = Provider.of<StoreProvider>(context);

    return FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      future: _services.products
          .where('published', isEqualTo: true)
          .where('categoryName.mainCategory',
              isEqualTo: _storeProvider.selectedProductCategory)
          .where('categoryName.subCategory', isEqualTo: _storeProvider.selectedSubCategory)
          .where('seller.sellerUid',
              isEqualTo: _storeProvider.storeDetails?['uid'])
          .get(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Text("Something Went Wrong");
        }
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
        return Column(
          children: [
            Material(
              elevation: 4,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Center(
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                        child: Text(
                          "${snapshot.data.docs.length} Items",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.grey[600],
                              fontSize: 18),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey[400],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
                height: 56,
              ),
            ),
            ListView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              children:
                  snapshot.data.docs.map<Widget>((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                return ProductCard(documentSnapshot: document);
              }).toList(),
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the code block

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('cart')
    .doc(user?.uid)
    .collection('products')
    .where('productId', isEqualTo: widget.documentSnapshot?['productId'])
    .get()
    .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
    if (doc['productId'] == widget.documentSnapshot?['productId']) {
      setState(() {
        exists = true;
        _qty = doc['qty'];
        _docId = doc.id;
      });
    }
  });
});
```

to `initState` instead of the `build`, this happens because you are `settingState` inside the build method, this might happen during the "building frame" process which will cause the issue you have

Moving the code block to initState will probably solve your issue

Comment: tried your solution but not worked, instead facing a new issue i.e when increasing the quantity count in AddToCardWidget it does not increase at the same time but have to navigate back and have to come again to AddToCardWidget to see the changes. Any other fix you may suggest ?
But the error has gone cheers for that.

Comment: Personally, I would prefer to use https://pub.dev/packages/event_bus to notify related screens
this works same as `Broadcast` in android and `local_notifications` in iOS,
it's simply an `event observer` where the screen you want to notify must be `subscribed` to a certain event, and to notify it just fire that event
**Note:** to make this work, you must have a `single instance` of the EventBus for the related screens

Comment: Thanks, will try it myself also. Really Appreciate your answers and support

Comment: It's pretty easy and useful, Good luck with it.  
Sure, no problem.